# Close PyWebView Window with HTML Button click

Tags: javascript, python, html, pywebview

**Info in advance:**

*There is a similar question dealing with the same issue.

However, this one doesn't work for me (or I just don't know enough to include it properly).

I have only recently started working with pywebview.*

**The goal:**

I want to close the window / end the programme with a link (or button) in `HTML`.

**The problem:**

The code used does not work for me.

The function can be reached (the print statement fills up the console,

unfortunately I have no idea why), but the window is not closed.

I am just starting with `pywebview`, so I don't really know what to do.

**Used pages for problem solving:**

[PyWebView Website](https://pywebview.flowrl.com/examples/destroy_window.html)

[StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65279193/how-to-close-pywebview-window-from-javascript-using-pywebview-api)

**The Code (Python & HTML):**

```
import sys

import webview


class Api:

    def __init__(self):
        self._window = None

    def set_window(self, window):
        self._window = window

    def destroy(window):
        print('Destroying window..')
        window.destroy()
        print('Destroyed!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    api = Api()
    window = webview.create_window('Blackjack', 'index.html', js_api=api, min_size=(1000, 800))
    webview.start()
```

```
<html>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div id="content">
                <a>
                    <div class="block" onclick="exit()">End</div>
                </a>
                <script>
                    function exit() { pywebview.api.destroy() }
                </script>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I have found a solution that closes the window and exits the program. 
However, I get an error, unfortunately I do not know why.

The **HTML / JS code is correct** so far and needs no adjustment.

In the **Python script**, only `def destroy(self)` must be specified instead of `def destroy(window)`.

*Pretty simple actually, but still took me almost a month to solve.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use that set_window method

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    api = Api()
    window = webview.create_window('Blackjack', 'index.html', js_api=api, min_size=(1000, 800))
    api.set_window(window)
    webview.start()
```